# What is the best way to send docker notifications to Elasticsearch?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, alert, docker-container, opensearch

We have docker running docker containers on different servers and we want to know when docker container is crashing.
We have Elasticsearch stack with Kibana.
So we think about the following pipeline:

- docker container stops
- docker sends alert to Elasticsearch
- Elasticsearch sends alert to our Slack channel

What is the best way to do the first part, when docker sends alert to elasticsearch?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The industry standard for alerting like that is to have an external watchdog service ([Nagios](https://www.nagios.org), [Kuma](https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma), etc) which would periodically run health check (a `GET /_cluster/health` request) and check that the cluster status is not "red". If the request fails or it's red - ping your Slack, PaderDuty, etc.

Comment: Thank you,
But i'm not sure how Elastic cluster will realize that one of the dockers stoped.

Comment: You can check `number_of_nodes` to detect disconnected nodes